# C++ Compressing eight booleans into a character

Tags: c++, compression, boolean, character

I have a large mass of integers that I'm reading from a file. All of them will be either 0 or 1, so I have converted each read integer to a boolean.

What I need to do is take advantage of the space (8 bits) that a character provides by packing every 8 bits/booleans into a single character. How can I do this?

I have experimented with binary operations, but I'm not coming up with what I want.

```
int count = 7;
unsigned char compressedValue = 0x00;
while(/*Not end of file*/)
{
    ...

    compressedValue |= booleanValue << count;

    count--;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        count = 7;
        //write char to stream
            compressedValue &= 0;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have updated the code to reflect some corrections suggested so far. My next question is, how should I initialize/clear the unsigned char?

**Update**

Reflected the changes to clear the character bits.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: hmm perhaps you should try to shifting left `<<`, `1 << count`

Comment: `unsigned char` is probably safer here than plain `char`.

Comment: After you've switched from `>>` to `<<`, you might also try counting from 7 down to 0 instead of 0 up to 7.

Comment: @Kerrek I figured that was going to be a problem. Thanks.

Comment: @aschepler Actually, I static cast it to an unsigned char when writing to the stream, like you said. But I can save myself a cast and just use unsigned from the getgo.

Comment: Hm, now keep in mind, with this implementation, I'm going to be using the same character and overwriting old bits after I've written them off. Is this going to be a problem with respect to the binary operations?

Comment: @Joseph: `|=` does not "overwrite" bits.

Comment: `std::bitset` and `std::vector<bool>` anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several notes:

- `while(!in.eof())` is wrong, you have to first try(!) to read something and if that succeeded, you can use the data.
- Use an unsigned char to get an integer of at least eight bits. Alternatively, look into stdint.h and use uint8_t (or uint_least8_t).
- The shift operation is in the wrong direction, use `uint8_t(1) << count` instead.
- If you want to do something like that in memory, I'd use a bigger type, like 32 or 64 bits, because reading a byte is still a single RAM access even if much more than a byte could be read at once.
- After writing a byte, don't forget to zero the temporary.

Comment: You're right about the eof(). I was simply indicating that there was a file being read. What do you mean about using a bigger type? The stream's `write()` uses a char*. If you're talking about modifying the output structure at a more fundamental level, I'm not really in a position to do that.

Comment: Using a bigger type was only if you want to handle the packed data in memory. The point is that a processor has registers and those registers are 32 or 64 bits nowadays. If you want to manipulate eight bits, you still need a whole register. Also, reading/writing RAM takes place in bigger pieces. So, in order to write eight bits, it might require loading 32 bits, overwriting eight of them and then writing the whole 32 back. In the case of file IO, that is the slowest part anyway, so there's no need for such optimizations.

Comment: I see. At this point I am simply compressing the size of the files. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

As Mooing Duck suggested, you can use a bitset.

The source code is only a proof of concept - especially the file-read has to be implemented.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

   char const fcontent[56] { "\0\001\0\001\0\001\0\001\0\001"
     "\001\001\001\001\001\001\001\001\001\001\001\001"
     "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
     "\0\001\0\001\0\001\0\001" };

   for( int i { 0 }; i < 56; i += 8 ) {
      std::bitset<8> const bs(fcontent+i, 8, '\0', '\001');
      std::cout << bs.to_ulong() << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
85 127 252 0 0 1 84
```

Answer (score -2):

The standard guaranties that `vector<bool>` is packed the way you want. Don't reinvent the wheel.[more info here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/)

Comment: It is not [guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool): `The manner in which std::vector<bool> is made space efficient (as well as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined.`

Comment: @stonemetal Nowhere in there does it say that it has to use sequential bits. As far as the standard is concerned, the implementation may use every second bit, every third bit or whatever it feels like. The only thing the standard requires is a `vector <bool>` with the interface given in 23.2.5.1.